# Identifying Stale Sites for Decommission

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, administration, storage

We are almost at the limit of our 17 TB capacity in SharePoint and storage is getting very expensive. Clean up activities are now underway and we want to identify and stale sites that can be decommissioned completely. Our criteria is anything over 1 year must be marked for deletion. The problem is, in the SharePoint admin center, the last modified date only goes back to 11/4/20 on ALL OLD sites!

This is not accurate, I know most of these sites haven't been touched in over a year yet it tells me November they were all modified on the same date. Is there a background process running that is updating this 'Last Modified' time stamp? How do we properly identify stale sites if this date isn't accurate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Emily. PowerShell helps here as well as MS graph API.
In the article above author use LastItemUserModifiedDate web property, but actually there are also

- LastContentModifiedDate Site property
- LastItemModifiedDate Web property
- LastModifiedDateTime MS Graph site property
  [Here are the differences](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/spo-site-lastcontentmodifieddate-vs-lastitemmodifieddate-vs-lastitemusermodifieddate/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find all unused sites by using PowerShell. Check whether the results are the same.

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/sharepoint-online-find-unused-sites-using-powershell.html

Comment: not sure why the downvote, I will try the Powershell

Comment: Unfortunately, these scripts rely on the Last Modified date which is mysteriously being updated on every site collection even inactive ones.

Comment: Since all site collections are  modified, you could check the retention policies.

Comment: Upvoted as Yes - PowerShell is your friend.